# Disable or bypass OAuth security for microservice-to-microservice communication in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have some microservices in Spring Boot and my front end application is in angular. I am using OpenID Connect for authentication and authorization. Right now, in my application, when the angular app is loaded, it redirects the user to the authentication server and after login the token is received which is sent by the angular application in each HTTP request to the resource servers. Now I have a question. My microservices also communicate with each other but as each microservice is acting as a resource server and the Rest APIs are secure now, so microservices can not communicate. What I want to achieve is that the requests which are sent by the user from the angular app should contain a token and those requests should be verified but I want to bypass or disable OAuth security for inter service-service communication between microservices. Is there any way to achieve this in Spring Boot?

Comment: Check OAuth2RestTemplate in Spring Boot.

Comment: I think, you are talking about making REST calls to an OAuth2 resource server but right now I want to disable or bypass OAuth2 security for service to service communication in my project.

Comment: You might use api gateway principle to outer requests require authorization while leaving inner requests unprotected.

Answer (score 1):

Do not disable OAuth2 security in your micro-services:

- if the inter-services request has the context of user (issued to satisfy part of an authorized request) just forward the original access-token
- if inter-services request is not originated by a user request / event / callback,... (scheduled task for instance), then it is possible to acquire an access-token using client credentials flow. Authorization-server should be configured to attach required roles to each client when it issues access-tokens with client credentials flow.

In first case, you can access bearer token from the Authentication in the security context. Add this Bearer string as Authorization header to the requests to other micro-services.

In second case configuring REST client (WebClient, RestTemplate, FeignClient, ...) with client credentials is usually enough for it to automatically fetch an access-token from the authorization-server and add it as bearer header before sending requests to the resource-server.

Comment: As far as I understood, you want to say that if I hit a Rest Api of a microservice, I should extract the token from the request and forward or insert it to another request which I want to send to another microservice internally but unfortunately, I have some scenarios in my application in which a request to another service will be triggered from a micro service internally when some event happens or some callback is triggered so in that case I shall not have a access token that only comes when a request is sent by the user from the browser.

Comment: Actually there are 3 cases: 1) a resource is public (access is allowed whatever the client, for instance legal notice); 2) resource is accessed on behalf of an authenticated user, in which case access-token (acquired with authorization code flow) should be forwarded as described in the answer; 3) resource is accessed by a robot in its own name (without any user context) in which case client-credentials flow should be used to get a new access-token (but resource should remain secured unless business decided it is public).

Comment: So we should use client-credentials flow for secure service to service communication. Right now, for user authentication and authorization, I am using Authorization Code Flow .

Comment: In first case, will it be more secure if issue a new token via cilent credential, and append the userinfo in the http header if needed? thus, the internal service will still be safe if the user token is stolen.

Comment: An access-token is something precious: if leaked their is a high risk of user identity usurpation. It should be exchanged solely between services you trust. The option you mention is achievable, but I don't see why this would add to security. IMO, it would just make security conf quite more complicated on the receiving side.